# Error using eclipse for Android - No resource found that matches the given name

Tags: android

Common problem I'm sure, but I can't figure it out.  In my AndroidManifest.xml and main.xml I'm getting the no resource found that matches the given name.  I've double checked for typos and it used to work, but now I'm popping up with all these errors saying it can't find my strings in my strings.xml.

These are the ones I'm getting errors for in my main.xml.

```
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:text="@string/instructions"    />

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:text="@string/level_prompt"    />

    <Spinner         
    android:id="@+id/spinner"        
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"        
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:prompt="@string/level_array"    />
```

These are the ones I'm getting for my androidmanifest.xml.

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
<activity android:name=".HelloFormStuff" android:label="@string/title">
```

This is what my strings.xml looks like.

```
<string name="title">Title</string>
<string name="app_name">Application name</string>

<string name="instructions">Enter instructions here.</string>

<string name="level_prompt">Choose an item</string>

<string-array name="level_array">        
<item>Item One</item>        
<item>Item Two</item>        
<item>Item Three</item>        
<item>Item Four</item>
</string-array>
```

Any ideas?  Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Accidentally moved the "values" folder outside of the "res" folder.  Moved it back and it fired up!

Comment: Please edit your original question or add a comment instead of a reply.

Comment: Thanks, I always get folder or files moving to other folders in Eclipse. sometimes just by double clicking on them in the package explorer. Annoying :/ But now, I just keep it in mind.

Comment: I accidentally moved the xml folder outside the res folder while implementing an account authenticator.  I ended up with the same error.

Answer (score 18):

This problem appeared for me due to an error in an XML layout file.  By changing `@id/meid` to `@+id/meid` (note the plus), I got it to work.  If not, sometimes you just gotta go to Project -> Clean...

Comment: This was exactly my issue.  Added the +, even to the @layout and it all compiles fine now.  Thanks!

Comment: i had the error when i entered a '?' in the strings file - solved it by escaping it :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575898/special-chars-as-xml-string-in-android-app

Answer (score 5):

I resolved this kind of issue like this: I went into my XML layout file, cut the line of code that was generating the error.  Then I saved the file, and pasted the code back in.  The error was gone.

Answer (score 4):

One general solution to such tiny errors is that you close eclipse and start is again.. 3 irritating problems were solved.. its the problem with eclipse.. some times it didn resolve "R.id", the it didn find @string/somebutton, and then again some random thing... if nothing logical comes in your mind, try this, n conjure d result.. :)

Comment: I was having several odd issues with eclipse today that I just couldn't figure out. It was saying that resources were missing or unable to be located when I could plainly see their existence. After trying everything I could think of on my own to get the Graphical Layout of the xml file to load I found this post. Restarted eclipse and all was well. In the future this will be the first thing I try when having a minor issue with a project in eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that you have

```
android:prompt="@string/level_array"
```

and you don't have any string with the id, to refer to the array, you need to use @array

test this or put a screen of your log please

Comment: @Sephy,

Commented out all code for the array, but it didn't help.  It's like the project isn't associating the strings.xml file to it.

Comment: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name'). AndroidManifest.xml /HelloFormStuff line 6 Android AAPT Problem

No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/title'). AndroidManifest.xml /HelloFormStuff line 7 Android AAPT Problem
No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/title'). AndroidManifest.xml /HelloFormStuff line 7 Android AAPT Problem

Comment: maybe it's just an error of writing on StackO, but is your string file named string or stringS.
because your wrote strings.xml here, an unfortunately, the correct spelling is without s...

Comment: It's named strings.xml, according to the "hello, world" on the android development site (yes I'm new at this language!) it's correct.  Ha, I just found it.  I accidentally moved the values folder outside of the "res" folder.  Moved it back and it fired up! 

Thanks Sephy for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: strangely enough, I have 2 string files (for I18n) one is string.xml and the other is strings.xml... and both are working. So I was wrong anyway...
couldn't have seen that you moved your file :D

Answer (score 1):

tried what KennyH write but it didn't solved my problem that appear while trying edit style.xml file in my android app,
so I just delete the project from eclipse (**not from disk of course !!**) and import it back ,solved it for me in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I renamed the file in res/values "strings.xml" to "string.xml" (no 's' on the end), cleaned and rebuilt without error.

Answer (score 0):

I actually has this problem once with a path issue referring another project :

I had this in my default.properties:

```
android.library.reference.1=..\\MyProject_Core\\
```

Which I fixed like this:

```
android.library.reference.1=../MyProject_Core/
```

My colleague created the above with Windows but only the version below worked on my Mac.

Answer (score 0):

If you are an iPhone Developer don't just add your picture (by right clicking then add file...like we do in iPhone). You have to copy and paste the picture in your drawable folder.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue appeared because my **string file could not be parsed**. I wanted to have a value  like `'%s - %s'`. However this appeared to be triggering a problem, it seems string will try to parse this value in a special way. Because two string values were provided in a single value an error was written in the console, but I had so many errors triggered from that, that the initial error was hidden, because of small console buffer. Adding `formatted="false"` attribute to this string value of mine fixed the problem in the string file (which btw was not reported as compilation error in the file itself) and I was able to build once more.

Answer (score 0):

Project ---> Clean does the trick in most of the cases. It did in mine.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse doesn't seem to like imported programs. What worked for me is renaming strings.xml to string.xml, save (without error) and then rename it back to strings.xml, save again and error doesn't show up again.

Eclipse would be sooo good if it wasn't for those tiny little errors all the time :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and tried most of the solutions mentioned above and they did not fix it.. 
At then end, I went to my `.csproj` file and viewed it in the text editor, I found that my xml file that I put in the `/Drawable` was not set to be `AndroidResouces` it was just of type `Content`.

Changing that to be of type `AndroidResouces` fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another Googlemare Landmine....

I solved this same problem today:
Somehow, if you mess up, the icon line on your .gen file dies. (Empirical proof of mine after struggling 2 hours)

Insert a new icon 72x72 icon on the hdpi folder with a different name from the original, and update the name on the manifest also.

The icon somehow resurrects on the Gen file and voila!! time to move on.

Answer (score -1):

I had problem with puuting background image. Error was the same. But I solved it by removing extension of file

android:background="@drawable/sky.png"  --->> android:background="@drawable/sky"

Comment: It's not relevant to the question. See his XML files!