# Android array cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, android, arrays, spinner

I have the following code segments in my program:

```
 ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> dataAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.datatypes, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

  ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> timeAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.timetypes, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

I am getting an error on "R.array" indicating that array cannot be resolved or is not a field.

This was working moments ago and I am unsure what I have this.

I have tried including "com.throughputconverter.R" and cleaning and rebuilding multiple times. I have also restarted eclipse.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Check for errors in any of your Layouts. If there is one, R is not auto-generated!

Comment: I've deleted my R and it auto generates.

Comment: I explained badly sorry. If there is any error in any of your xmls then new entries won't be generated

Comment: the only layout I have is main.xml and it has no errors.

Comment: shut eclipse down and manually delete R.java, when you turn eclipse back on and open the project it will automatically auto-generate R.java, clean, recompile and try again.

Comment: I did that I still have errors. My array is defined in my strings.xml, I think there's an issue with that not being linked to my project

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477647/error-using-eclipse-for-android-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name Solved the problem I was having

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Error using eclipse for Android - No resource found that matches the given name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477647/error-using-eclipse-for-android-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name)

Solved the problem I was having

Answer (score 0):

another solution here is to create the R manually..just hover to your error in the activity file where the problem was..and then manually create it...and R will generate the string array you created in strings.xml