# Array cannot be resolved for sports_array

Tags: java, android, arrays, eclipse

Initially my array looks like this:

```
<string-array name="sports_array">
    <item>Shuttle Badminton</item>
    <item>Tennis</item>
    <item>Table Tennis</item>
    <item>Basket Ball</item>
    <item>Foot Ball</item>
    <item>Volley Ball</item>
    <item>Hockey</item>
    <item>Swimming</item>
</string-array>
```

It was located in string.xml but when I tried to use this code to retrieve it, it does not display the array. The error that I get is Array cannot be resolved or is not a field.

```
String[] sports = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sports_array);
```

I cleaned my project twice and the error is still there but what I didn't realize what the array that I placed in the `string.xml` disappeared. So I went on reading a few questions here and one of the options is to create an `array.xml` and place my arrays there instead of in `string.xml`. I still get the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just checking did you accidentally moved the "values" folder outside of the "res" folder like this :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252098/android-array-cannot-be-resolved-or-is-not-a-field  ?

Comment: `R` java class is missing the `array` class since the resource was not loaded properly. Make sure you don't have hidden XML errors in your resource files.

Comment: does your class extend activity?

Comment: I solved it. I just put it back in string.xml and it works again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this solution.

create `fetcharr.xml` in **res/values/fetcharr.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <string-array name="sports_array">
            <item>Tennis</item>
            <item>Table Tennis</item>
            <item>Basket Ball>
        </string-array>
    </resources>

now  in activity class
Resources res = getResources();
String[] planets = res.getStringArray(R.array.sports_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that you have defined this in strings.xml: 
`<string name="action_settings">Action Settings</string>`