# special chars (@, ?) as xml-string in android app

Tags: android

If i try to do things like this, it doesn't work...
(empty string or no resource type error)

```
<string name="random">?</string>
<string name="random">@</string>
```

i also tried the html entity variant

```
<string name="random">&#63;</string>
```

any ideas how to use the "?" and "@" as string resource in android?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Easiest way is to quote or backslash them:

```
<string name="random">"?"</string>
<string name="random">\?</string>
```

See [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/bd5dc0f6791b18f7?pli=1) and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling) for a bit more discussion.

- [`?` reference styling attributes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ReferencesToThemeAttributes)
- [`@` signs access other resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ResourcesFromXml).

Here's a [larger collection of string resource gotchas](https://tekeye.uk/android/examples/android-string-resources-gotchas).

Answer (score 2):

This is working for me:

```
<string name="twitter_hint">"@"twitter</string>
```

Comment: AnshulParashar  try this <string name="twitter_hint">"\@twitter"</string>