# How to use @ in string resource android

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to achieve something line this

```
<string name="copyright">@2021 Ruma. All rights reserved</string>
```

But it seams @ can't be used there.
Error:- Missing /

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Put a backslash in front of it to escape it. But shouldn’t that be a copyright symbol instead of an at sign?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [special chars (@, ?) as xml-string in android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575898/special-chars-as-xml-string-in-android-app)

Answer (score 2):

The @ character is a special character that needs to be escaped https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#escaping_quotes

```
<string name="copyright">\@2021 Ruma. All rights reserved</string>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think when you insert forward slash in front of @ to escape you may see forward slash as text in UI .
[image]

To avoid this you can use HTML Tag `<b></b>` to get Bold or `<i></i>` to get italic.

```
    <string name="copyright"><b>@2021 Ruma. All rights reserved</b></string>
```

[image]

Comment: That's a forward slash

Comment: Yes I got that later . Thanks .

Answer (score 1):

Try the unicode symbol "\u00a9"

Answer (score 1):

You may use unicodes.
Get the appropriate value from somewhere & append to the '\u'

Ex:
https://unicode-table.com/en/#basic-latin

```
<string name="copyright">\u0040 2021 Ruma. All rights reserved</string>
```