# message displayed when trying to run

Tags: android, eclipse, string

error : Error: no resource found that matches the given name (at "hint" with value "@string/edit_message")

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send" />
```

Comment: please check in your `strings.xml` whether it contains some text for edit_message..

Comment: if there is a value in `strings.xml` for edit_message, you may just need to do a clean build (rebuild R.java)

Comment: not sure but please clean your project then try it might be work

Answer (score 0):

Check that wheather you have accidently moved your `values` folder out of the `res` folder.

This can be also caused by the error in xml layout file..You must change `@id/meid` to `@+id/meid`

See some more info by going [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477647/error-using-eclipse-for-android-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the string "edit_message" inside your `res/values/strings.xml` file.

add the value, for example:

**strings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
...
...
    <string name="edit_message">This is my edit message!</string>   
...
...    
</resources>
```