# material-dialog lib, error: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog.Alert'

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library, material-design

I am trying to import [this material-dialog library](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs).
Getting this error: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog.Alert'.

Getting it in file: values-v21/styles.xml.
[image]

I am using Eclipse and I have imported android-support-v4.jar in libs folder. What could be the issue here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error using eclipse for Android - No resource found that matches the given name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477647/error-using-eclipse-for-android-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your project properties, make sure that you have selected API level 21 as your platform. Also, in your manifest file, make `targetSdkVersion` as 21. Then clean & rebuild your project, and it should work.

Whenever you use the new `Material Design` features or the newest version of the support library, the project needs to be compiled against API level 21.

Answer (score 1):

As a reference for others running into this issue, make sure you've prefixed the name of the parent theme with `android:`, so the full parent tag will look like this:

```
parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog.Alert">
```

I was getting the same error because I copied some code the didn't include that prefix for some reason.