# No resource found that matches the given name, where I do something wrong?

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin

I can't figure why I get this error :

```
no resource found that matches the given name
```

I have a folder called "anim" inside the Resources folder, inside the anim folder I have 2 files: slide_up.xml and slide_right.xml

Here is my style file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.Splash" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">0dp</item>
  </style>  

<style name="DialogAnimation">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_up</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_right</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

I am keep getting this error every time I am tiring to build the project, I am 100% sure that the file names and the path are correct, so why the project doesn't recognize the files ?

Edit : This is how I call the animation :

```
public override void OnActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    Dialog.Window.RequestFeature (WindowFeatures.NoTitle); //Sets the title bar to invisible
    base.OnActivityCreated (savedInstanceState);
    Dialog.Window.Attributes.WindowAnimations = Resource.Style.DialogAnimation; //Sets the animation
}
```

Comment: Do you have the `slide_up.xml` and `slide_right.xml` inside of Drawable folder?

Comment: No, as I said they are inside the anim folder, I did try to make in work in drawable folder but it's didn't work either.. I thought maybe this is a bug and even restarted my computer because I can't see any mistake there..

Comment: Show me how you are calling this on java code please

Comment: Do you added the files to Xamarin project ? As you may know xamarin is not mirroring folder files inside project you should add them in the project , if they are added right click on them and select build type > android resource.

Comment: put `slide_up.xml` and `slide_right.xml` in `drawables` folder and change `@anim/slide_up` to `@drawable/slide_up`

Comment: I am using c#, I tagged java because its probably the same thing in the style file and I was thinking the problem is there.. Anyways here how i call it the c# :  Dialog.Window.RequestFeature (WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
   base.OnActivityCreated (savedInstanceState);
   Dialog.Window.Attributes.WindowAnimations = Resource.Style.DialogAnimation;

Comment: @hrskrs I just tried that mate, same error . Anything else maybe that you could think of ?

Comment: As @Skizo said, can you please show the code where you are using `DialogAnimation` so we can identify it, from what we see we can only sugesst what we have suggested

Comment: @hrskrs I have edited the question, please take a look, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for helping me out but I have figured out the answer, its was pretty simple but I really have no idea why this happens because in every other place in the code everything works fine.

I found the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477647/error-using-eclipse-for-android-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name), by Stephen Wylie and I quote the answer :

"This problem appeared for me due to an error in an XML layout file. By changing @id/meid to @+id/meid (note the plus), I got it to work. If not, sometimes you just gotta go to Project -> Clean"

As soon as I added "+" to the "@anim/slide_up" so now its like "@+anim/slide_up" the code seems to work.

I posted this just in-case someone else will have the same struggle because I was trying to fix this for 5 hours now..

Comment: Well thats why you should post your question clearly. As you didnt post the `xml` file we cannot identify that error. Anyway glad you solved it

Comment: Putting the "+" depends on the xml file ? I am just wondering for future knowledge, and Thank you I am also glad :)

Answer (score 1):

From API guides->animation resources->View animation:
resource reference:In Java:

```
R.anim.filename
```

In XML:

```
@[package:]anim/filename
```

Maybe try adding the package?

Comment: What exactly package we are talking about ? It's a basic animation and if I understand correctly there is no need in any package ? am I wrong ? Please note that I am using c# but answer is java work for me as well because I know how to insert this in the project.

Comment: Look at the first line of your .java file that you are calling your animation with, it's usually there. it's like "yourname.yourappname". For example, whenever in java you reference R, you can say "yourname.yourappname.R.layout.myLayout", instead of "R.layout.myLayout", but the latter is enough because of this first line.